# password_verify doesn't verify hash

Tags: php, hash, verification, password-encryption

I hash my inserted passwords via password_hash. I verify them by using password_verify.

However when I insert a hashed password in my database and I try to verify it, both outputs always differ from eachother.

my pages are as following,

main_login.php (form):

```
<?php include 'header.php';?>
<body>
<form role="form" method="post" action="login.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="usrname">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="usrname" placeholder="Enter username">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="passwrd">Password:</label>
  </div>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="passwrd" placeholder="Enter password">
    <br>
  <input type="checkbox">Remember Me
  <br>
  <br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

login.php (handler):

```
<?php
include 'vars.php';
include 'header.php';
$sql="SELECT * FROM members WHERE usrname='$usrname'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$verify=password_verify($hash,$row[2]);
if($verify){
    $_SESSION["usrname"]=$usrname;
    echo "Correct";
}
else {
    echo "user: " . $usrname. "<br>";
    echo "pass: " . $hash. "<br>";
    echo "db: " . $row[2]."<br>";
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

vars.php:

```
<?php
$h='localhost';$u='caelin';$p='****';$d='ombouwnh';
$con=mysqli_connect($h,$u,$p,$d);
$usrname=$_POST['usrname'];
$passwrd=$_POST['passwrd'];
$hash=password_hash($passwrd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
?>
```

when i try to login using username 'caca' and password 'caca' I get a different output for both, everytime i retry.
I can't find this particular problem on stackoverflow.

TIA

PS. If you need more details, ask for them

Comment: Make sure the columns length is long enough to accomodate the hash; that is usually an error many make.

Comment: it is varchar(255) @Fred-ii-

Comment: `$row[2]` make sure that number is correct. That is indeed the 3rd column in your table, correct? Plus you do have `session_start();` loaded, right? `$_SESSION["usrname"]` may be irrelevant.

Comment: The moment you're called in to work on a project, finding out all column names lack one or two letters ...

Comment: Is this a problem? @Sherlock

Comment: Your hash seems to be the 2nd column, so you would need to do `$row[1]` - Arrays start at zero and not one.

Comment: Not with regards to this problem, but in general: yes, it's a huge pain in the behind.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Do I have to start a session before the user is actually logged in? Sorry for the newb question

Comment: It's required when using session variables; yes. Did you read my comment about `$row[1]`?

Comment: I did, but my hash is stored in the password row, which is row 3, and that's why I suppose I have to do row[2]@Fred-ii-

Comment: Ah ok. I wasn't sure since I noticed `echo "user: " . $usrname. "<br>";
    echo "pass: " . $hash. "<br>";
    echo "db: " . $row[2]."<br>";` which seemed that something did not match.

Comment: and also with session_start(); still same problem. @Fred-ii-

Comment: Why are you hashing the user input password? password_verify takes a non-hashed input and compares it to a stored hash. Try not hashing the password being passed to password_verify.

Comment: You are awesome @AndrewHotovy. If you put it in an answer I'll accept it

Comment: I can post an answer below with something that I use myself if you can't get yours to work. @caelin

Comment: @caelin I have to kind of **warn/caution** you about echoing `echo "db: " . $row[2]."<br>";` - If someone enters (or guesses) a correct/existing username and either no password or an incorrect password, it will display the hashed password for that user. I recommend not echoing that row at all, if that will be part of your working code. This I've gathered by testing your code and the solution provided.

Comment: @Fred-ii- This was pure for testing and I will not use it for my workimg code.

Comment: @caelin Ah, ok. I just had to make sure.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The function `password_verify();` takes two parameters; a non-hashed input, and a stored hash to compare it to. It hashes the non-hashed input automatically to compared it to the stored version. So your initial code was re-hashing an already hashed password. Should look like this:

```
$verify=password_verify($_POST['passwrd'],$row[2]);

if($verify){
    $_SESSION["usrname"]=$usrname;
    echo "Correct";
}
else {
    echo "user: " . $usrname. "<br>";
    echo "pass: " . $hash. "<br>";
    echo "db: " . $row[2]."<br>";
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
```

Comment: Way to go Andrew. I'm glad the OP got the solution. I asked the OP if he/she wanted me to post something I use myself, before I saw your comment. It's always best to work with OP's code and finding the solution to the actual problem instead of someone else's code. *Cheers* +1

Answer (score 3):

You rehashed the password - just pass the plaintext password and your hash (from db) to password_verify and it works.

Comment: It's been answered 20 minutes prior, and accepted; thank you.

Comment: Sorry, opened the question and typed up the reply but couldn't post until my wifi connection got fixed (for