# password_verify always returns as false

Tags: php, sql, password-hash

I've got a light application i'm putting together as I get myself started, and I'm a touch confused.

I've set my database column for passwords to be 255, and used the password_hash function to get a hash, which I inserted.

But now the following ALWAYS returns false;

```
if (isset($_POST[submit])) {
    $link = mysqli_init();
    
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `admins` WHERE `username` = (?)");
    $query->bind_param('s', $username);
    echo $mysqli->error;
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    print_r($result);

    if (!$result) {
        echo '<p class="error">Username password combination is wrong!</p>';
    } else {
        if (password_verify($password, $result['password'])) {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $result['id'];
            header('Location: results.php');
        } else {
            echo '<p class="error">Username password combination is wrong!</p>';
        }
    }
}
```

Its just a small login form, a username, a password field and a submit button, but no matter what I try, every solution here seems to mention a column length being 60, and should be 255, which mine is. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit; updated the snippet to show more... result isn't printing which means its not getting anything from what I can tell?

Comment: Check the most basic steps first: is `$password` the unaltered password from the input and is it correct?

Comment: There's not enough information here to allow us to determine what the issue is. What debugging have you done so far?

Comment: Have you checked what `$result['password']` is? Can you show us your `password_hash` implementation?

Comment: First parameter is the original password, second parameter is the hash (from password_hash()). Please read the documentation instead of guessing things...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [password\_verify doesn't verify hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26721833/password-verify-doesnt-verify-hash)

Comment: @LarsStegelitz It seems to me that's the exact order in OP's code (`$result` seems to be the DB row, judging by further use).

Comment: Updated to show more stuff folk, apologies, it seems result isn't pulling anything?

Comment: You're binding the password to the where clause, but you're looking for the username, switch `$password` binding to `$username` instead.

Comment: _"...result isn't printing..."_ - are you saying you're not seeing the `print_r` at all?

Comment: You also create the variable `$link`, while using `$conn` afterwards. You should always check your error logs or [display PHP errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) while developing.

Comment: FYI as an aside, `if ($conn->connect_error) { echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);` is a mess. 1) "could not able to" isn't grammatically correct English. You could say "Unable to" instead. 2) `execute` makes no sense here because the error is triggered by connecting to the DB, not executing a query. Change `execute` to `connect`. 3)  `mysqli_error` doesn't report connection errors. 4) `$conn` doesn't seem to exist - `$mysqli` is your connection object. Change to `if ($mysqli->connect_error)` and then also echo `$mysqli->connect_error` instead of mysqli_error

Comment: aside cont'd.... 5) `$sql` is defined in that context either. Fully changed code: `if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        echo "ERROR: Unable to connect - " .$mysqli->connect_error;`. 6) You really need to stop the script there with `exit();` if the connection fails, because you can't do anything else useful after that. Otherwise you'll just end up with more errors where the code tries to run queries without a valid connection.

Comment: But better still, avoid all the clumsy if statements for error checking by just telling mysqli to throw exceptions properly. (Obviously this requires you to also have error logging enabled in PHP.) See these guides if you need help setting those things up: https://stackify.com/php-error-logs-guide/ (php error logging/reporting)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/5947043 (mysqli exception reporting)

Comment: Thanks for the asides, this is all new to me so I'm piecing it all together, english isn't native either so thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured the problem out.

I'd not included a bind_result to lock the results down in a way I could access, the below code worked correctly.

```
if (isset($_POST[submit])) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `admins` WHERE `username` = ?");
    $query->bind_param('s', $username);
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($id, $user, $pass);
    $result = $query->fetch();

    print_r($pass);

    if (!$result) {
        echo '<p class="error">Username password combination is wrong!</p>';
    } else {
        if (password_verify($password, $pass)) {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;
            header('Location: results.php');
        } else {
            echo '<p class="error">Username password combination is wrong!</p>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ....out of curiosity:executing that code is not triggering a warning that the constant `submit` hasn't been defined?

Comment: It is yeah, thats my next thing to work through. Do I just... declare it somewhere? Its the submit button on the HTML form that calls it, which works for now, just unsure what the fix is.. this is all pretty new to me

Comment: It merely needs to be quoted. An associative index is a string.

Comment: Did you declare that constant anywhere or didn't you? Adding a button to a HTML form is not the same as declaring a constant, so probably you want to use `$_POST['submit']`